# javascript Access parent from event listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a wrapper for google map api.  The following function is part of an object. I keep getting "self is undefined". Typically the listener only has function(event), I tried adding self to the parameter list to get access to the parent object.

```
var self = this;

google.maps.event.addListener(this.geoMarker, 'dragend', function( event, self ){

      //update input 
      self.lat = event.latLng.lat(); //ERROR: self is undefined
      self.lng = event.latLng.lng();


      //udpate any fields that were set
      self.updateDisplay();  

      self.geoMarker.setTitle("Lat: " + event.latLng.lat() + '   Lng: ' + event.latLng.lat() );

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the declaration of `self` from the callback's parameter list - it's over-riding the external declaration.

Comment: perfect thanks, you'll get the check after the waiting period ends.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second parameter (self) from the callback function